# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method rexUrlRewriter::rexUrlRewriter()

Tags: php, constructor

I am getting the error above using PHP7. Can anyone tell me, how to fix it?

```
class rexUrlRewriter
{    
  function __construct()
  {
    // do nothing    
  }
}

class myUrlRewriter extends rexUrlRewriter
{
  function __construct($use_levenshtein = false, $use_params_rewrite = false)
  {   
    parent::rexUrlRewriter();
  }
```

Comment: I think you need to call parent::__construct(). Is that what you intended to do ?

Answer (score 0):

> parent::***rexUrlRewriter();***
>
> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method rexUrlRewriter::rexUrlRewriter()

Through this `parent::rexUrlRewriter();` you are actually trying to call a static method `rexUrlRewriter` of class `rexUrlRewriter`, for calling parent class constructor use `parent::__construct(...);`

**Change this to:**

```
class myUrlRewriter extends rexUrlRewriter
{
  function __construct($use_levenshtein = false, $use_params_rewrite = false)
  {   
    parent::rexUrlRewriter();
  }
```

**This:**

```
class myUrlRewriter extends rexUrlRewriter
{
  function __construct($use_levenshtein = false, $use_params_rewrite = false)
  {   
    parent::_construct();//Added this line to call parent class constructor
  }
}
```